# Ошибка Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `main`.`new_comment`.`film_id` at row

Tags: php, pdo

У меня появилась ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]:Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `main`.`new_comment`.`film_id` at row 1 in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\includes\connection.php:159 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\includes\connection.php(159): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\includes\addcomment.php(6): DB->addComment() #2 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\includes\connection.php on line 159

Код:

```
public function addComment () {
    global $film_name;

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT film_id FROM new_film WHERE film_name = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$film_name]);
    $film_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    $user_name = $_POST['username'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO new_comment (author, text, pubgdate, film_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute([$user_name, $comment, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $film_id]);
  }
```

Что делать?

Comment: "Что делать?" -> `дебажить`

Comment: Что в `$film_id` лежит?

Comment: Я завардампил вернуло почемуто bool(false)

Comment: Ну вот и ответ на ваш вопрос. Вообще, тут если просто ошибку перевести то уже более-менее понятно становится.. Проверьте запрос

Comment: Проблема в том, что $film_name почему-то не передается. Я и пробовал через $_SESSION['film_name] = $film_name и в этом файле я принял $film_name = $_SESSION['film_name']

Comment: а зачем в сессию? Как вызывается функция `addComment ()` у вас? Можно просто имя в параметры передавать